# Google Script Copy Last Row, All Columns from

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Two tabs on a Sheet named Master and Working.

"Master" Sheet is populated by an import range from a separate google sheet which is populated by a jotform submission.
=IMPORTRANGE("1YIxcke-hskw2NyokxtnWoDO_69hz_K-CXfsIq0Z3yNM", "Sheet1!A:MO")

My need is when a new submission hits "Master" the script runs to copy the new row to "Working" with select Columns.

I have two Scripts currently. The manual copy version works fine but only works on the active cell. The onEdit version does not copy anything when you run it. I have a feeling this is related to the importrange making the "last row" an empty row.

This is my script:

```
function onEdit(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
var );
Logger.log(rowValues);
var destValues = [];
destValues.push(rowValues[0][0]);// copy data from col A to col A
destValues.push(rowValues[0][1]);// copy data from col B to col B
destValues.push(rowValues[0][2]);// copy data from col C to col C

destValues.push(rowValues[0][5]);// copy data from col F to col D
destValues.push(rowValues[0][6]);// copy data from col G to col E
destValues.push(rowValues[0][7]);// copy data from col H to col F
destValues.push(rowValues[0][8]);// copy data from col I to col G

destValues.push(rowValues[0][21]);// copy data from col V to col H

destValues.push(rowValues[0][23]);// copy data from col X to col I

var dest = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Working");

dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length) 
.setValues([destValues]);
}
```

(I had to break up the dest.getRange line to make it format as code.)

This is a copy of my sheet, shared: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FylLCocxDmKYISzjuFeSCSLUgE4kbBtkDPk-zI698JQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: From your script, do you see any useful messages in View->Execution Transcript?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the code is attempting to write to a row that does not exist.

Replace

```
dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length) 
   .setValues([destValues]);
```

With

```
dest.appendRow(destValues)
```

The function "appendRow" exits on the the Sheet object.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)

It expects an array of values.

The setValues function you have been calling expects and array of arrays.

Comment: Sorry, not clear on what that suggestion replaces or if it is an addition. I guessed and tried a few combos and get an error running the script.

Comment: I clarified my answer.  I will be curious to hear if that helps.

Comment: Updated to append and get this error: TypeError: Cannot find function appendRow in object Range. (line 22, file "Code")

Looking at your other comment. The View Execution Transcript confirms my suspicion. The get last row is going all the way down to row 1000 and copying a blank row from Master to Working even though the contents of Master stops at Row 29. 

The ImportRange seems to be causing false populated cells. 

Is there a better function to use to get live/real time data from another google sheet?

Comment: @MikeT, I updated the answer.  Perhaps that will help.

Comment: Thank you for replying again. I ended up fixing it by not using the ImportRange to make an active copy of the sheet. Instead I am now using the same script but sending the last row on change to the desired sheet. 

 var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID#').getSheetByName('Working');
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);